# Label for Solo Text Field in Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

Anyone know of a way to add a label to a solo style text field for Vuetify? Its not even working on Vuetify's own website. [Here is a link that shows it not working:](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#example-solo)

And here is the code with the `label` props from Vuetify, this also does not work:

```
<template>
  <v-container grid-list-md>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6>
        <v-text-field solo label="First Name" v-model="first"></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6>
        <v-text-field solo-inverted label="Last Name" v-model="last"></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: You mean label above it when input is not empty? I believe it's working as intended atm.

Answer (score 0):

The `label`, when `solo` is setted to true, just is showed if the `input` is empty. If it's not, it will just show what you have typed.